# Can I use log and without any transformation variables in the one model for the independent variables?

Tags: regression

Can I use log-log/linear regression models by taking the natural logarithm of some variables?

Imagine I have a dependent variable $y$ and independent variables $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$. Can I run the following regression:

$$\log(y) = \log(x_1)+\log(x_2) + x_3$$

Comment: What is name of that model?log(y)=log(x1)+log(x2)+x3

Answer (score 5):

You can absolutely mix logged and unlogged variables on the right hand side. For example, one never logs dummy or negative variables for obvious reasons.

However, I do think it is good to have principled reasons for doing this in your analysis.